# Como saber cual fue el producto mas vendido: SQL

Tags: sql

tengo la siguientes tablas :

```
SELECT [idVenta]      SELECT [id_venta]
      ,[FechaHora]           ,[id_articulo]
      ,[id_usuario]          ,[cantidad]
      ,[id_cliente]          ,[sub_total]                      
      ,[total]                FROM detalle_venta
  FROM venta                   
 
SELECT [idArticulo]
      ,[nombreArt]
      ,[precio]
      ,[stock]
      ,[descripcion]
      ,[id_proveedor]
  FROM articulo
```

Quería saber con una consulta SQL cual fue el producto mas vendido. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado hacer?¿qué problema te da?

Comment: Creo que te hace falta dar más detalles a la pregunta y que nos digas que has intentado.

Comment: Intente hacer el código que menciona Omar, pero arroja el siguiente error:***Column 'articulo.nombreArt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.***

Comment: Listo muchachos, adjunto lo que precisaba:

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 nombreArt,SUM(cantidad) AS VENDIDOS FROM detalle_venta 
INNER JOIN articulo on detalle_venta.id_articulo = articulo.idArticulo
GROUP BY nombreArt Order by VENDIDOS desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no lo entiendo mal debería ser algo así.

```
SELECT articulo.nombreArt, SUM(detalle_venta.cantidad) as cantidad
    FROM detalle_venta JOIN articulo ON detalle_venta.id_articulo = articulo.idArticulo
    GROUP BY articulo.idArticulo
    ORDER BY SUM(detalle_venta.cantidad) DESC LIMIT 1;
```